# In lighthouse-php, How can i define a type for a model with a difftent name?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am using lighthouse package for graphql in laravel, i need to declare a type for a model lets say "ClassA", but the type name must be TypeA, what is the best practice to do so?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to do this...
`type Query { 
  typea(id: ID @eq): TypeA @find(model: "App\\Models\\ClassA")
}
type TypeA {
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not add it on the type itself, you add in in the query.
So to follow your example you would do

```
type TypeA {
   ...
}

type Query {
 typeA(id: ID @eq): TypeA @find(model: "TypeA")
 typeAs(): [TypeA] @all(model: "TypeA")
}
```

You can find it in the [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#all) also.